# Spring MongoDB mapping OAuth2Authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I'm writing my own implementation of TokenStore (org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore) using MongoDB. There seems to be some problem with converting/mapping of the object in the database back to Java object.

Anyone have a clue how I could solve this?

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments 
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1185) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a converter and register it as Spring Mongo doesn't do this for you.

**Create a converter**

```
import com.erranda.abraham.entity.Person;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.convert.ReadingConverter;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request;

import java.util.*;

/**
 * @version 1.0
 * @author: Iain Porter
 * @since 23/05/2013
 */
//Hackery to deserialize back into an OAuth2Authentication Object made necessary because Spring Mongo can't map clientAuthentication to authorizationRequest
@ReadingConverter
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class OAuth2AuthenticationReadConverter implements Converter<DBObject, OAuth2Authentication> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public OAuth2Authentication convert(DBObject source) {
        System.out.println(source);
        DBObject storedRequest = (DBObject)source.get("storedRequest");

        OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request((Map<String, String>)storedRequest.get("requestParameters"),
                (String)storedRequest.get("clientId"), null, true, new HashSet((List)storedRequest.get("scope")),
                null, null, null, null);
        DBObject userAuthorization = (DBObject)source.get("userAuthentication");
        Object principal = getPrincipalObject(userAuthorization.get("principal"));

        Authentication userAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal,
                (String)userAuthorization.get("credentials"), getAuthorities((List) userAuthorization.get("authorities")));

        OAuth2Authentication authentication = new OAuth2Authentication(oAuth2Request,
                userAuthentication );
        return authentication;
    }

    private Object getPrincipalObject(Object principal) {
        if(principal instanceof DBObject) {
            DBObject principalDBObject = (DBObject)principal;
            Person user = new Person (principalDBObject);
            return user;
        } else {
            return principal;
        }
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(List<Map<String, String>> authorities) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>(authorities.size());
        for(Map<String, String> authority : authorities) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.get("role")));
        }
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

}
```

**Then you need to register converter along side your mongodb configuration**

```
import com.erranda.abraham.api.security.OAuth2AuthenticationReadConverter;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.CustomConversions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class MongoDbConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MongoDbConfiguration.class);
    private static final String MONGO_DB_SERVER = "mongo.db.server";
    private static final String MONGO_DB_PORT = "mongo.db.port";
    private static final String MONGO_DB_NAME = "mongo.db.name";
    private static final String MONGO_DB_LOGON = "mongo.db.logon";
    private static final String MONGO_DB_PASSWORD = "mongo.db.password";
    private static final String SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "spring.profiles.active";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Value("${" + MONGO_DB_SERVER + "}")
    private String mongoServer;
    @Value("${" + MONGO_DB_PORT + "}")
    private int mongoPort;
    @Value("${" + MONGO_DB_NAME + "}")
    private String mongoDBName;
    @Value("${" + MONGO_DB_LOGON + "}")
    private String mongoDbLogin;
    @Value("${" + MONGO_DB_PASSWORD + "}")
    private String mongoDbPassword;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return mongoDBName;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new Mongo(mongoServer, mongoPort);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(mongoDbLogin)) {
            LOG.info("Configuring mongoTemplate with credentials.");
            MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo(), mongoDBName, new UserCredentials(mongoDbLogin, mongoDbPassword));
            return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, mappingMongoConverter());
        } else {
            LOG.info("Configuring mongoTemplate without credentials.");
            MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo(), mongoDBName);
            return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, mappingMongoConverter());
        }
    }


    @Override
    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
        OAuth2AuthenticationReadConverter converter = new OAuth2AuthenticationReadConverter();
        converterList.add(converter);
        return new CustomConversions(converterList);
    }



    private String getContextProperty(final String propertyKey) {
        return applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty(propertyKey);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to mark as correct if it works for you.

Based on https://github.com/iainporter/oauth2-provider

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I actually found this previously, but changed to Spring Data JPA (SQL Server) instead, because of all workarounds to cope with MongoDB.

Comment: Great. Thanks for marking. Good luck with your project.