# No converter found capable of converting from type com.mongodb.BasicDBObject to type org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authenticatio

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-mongodb, spring-oauth2

I am using the following and using following libraries:

spring-boot : 1.5.4

spring-security - 3.2.7

spring-oauth : 2.0.7

spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb : 1.5.4

spring-data-mongodb : 1.10.4

When I try get oauthtoken using this POST url:
http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=abc&password=xyz&client_id=testing&client_secret=testing using postman I get this error :

```
 {
"error": "server_error",
"error_description": "No converter found capable of converting from type [com.mongodb.BasicDBObject] to type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication]"
}
```

Please help

Regards

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to provide a converter from DBObject to OAuth2Authentication, I referred to this link [Set MongoDb converter programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780692/set-mongodb-converter-programmatically)
for registering programatically the converters

```
MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(mongoDbFactory, context);
converter.setTypeMapper(mapper);
converter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(
    Arrays.asList(
            new TimeZoneReadConverter(),
            new TimeZoneWriteConverter()
    )
 ));
converter.afterPropertiesSet();
MongoTemplate template = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
```

and this link [Spring MongoDB mapping OAuth2Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818759/spring-mongodb-mapping-oauth2authentication) which converts DBObject to OAuth2Authentication and I resolved this issue.

Regards

kris